# Joomla Month name not translated

Tags: joomla

I am using Joomla 2.5.28 and the latest Language Pack for German.

When I try to display the month from the creation date of the article it is not translated.

```
<?php echo JText::sprintf( JHTML::_('date',$this->item->created, JText::_('F'))); ?>
```

All other things work get translated as expected – the day of the week 'l', and short month "M", only the full month "F" doesn't.

Any ideas how to get it to display the german month name?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK JText::_("F") will not return you anything, since the string "F" does not exist in any Joomla language file. If you meant to pass a format string to the "date" method, use just

```
echo JText::sprintf( JHTML::_('date',$this->item->created, 'F'));
```

Unfortunately the PHP "date" command is not meant to translate strings, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php:

> To format dates in other languages, you should use the setlocale() and
>   strftime() functions instead of date().

Sorry I don't have a better answer than this :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, this also gives the english month name.

Comment: You're right. I've edited my answer with additional info

Comment: Are you positive the language files include the strings you want?

Answer (score 0):

Created a language override:
Go to Extensions -> Language Manager.
Click on Overrides tab.
Click on New.
"Constant" value: for example "DATE_FORMAT_LC6".
Change the text for your date format "F".
Use it as follows
echo JHTML::*('date', $item->created, JText::*('DATE_FORMAT_LC6'));